# tweaking stored proc

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, where-clause, ssms-2016

I have a stored proc that gets called with a parameter. I would like to check what the PARAM @Value is, and depending on the value, I want to add a part of a WHERE clause if it equals to a certain value.

Let's say the proc looks like this:

```
  Select Sum(Cost) as Cost, Car, Make
  INTO #TempTable1
  WHERE 
  1=1 and Date > '04/21/2020'

  IF @Value in (1,2,3)
  AND Color= 'Black'

  GROUP BY
  Car, Make
```

This is a much simpliefied code, my WHERE clause for @Value=1,2,3 will be much bigger.

So essentially, my goal is to add part of WHERE clause if the @Value = 1, 2, 3. Is something like doable?

EDIT:
What if above my select statement i add something like

```
 DECLARE @WHERE AS VARCHAR(MAX)
 IF @VALUE IN (1,2,3) 
   SET @WHERE = 'color = ''black'''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the condition :

```
AND ((@VALUE IN (1,2,3) AND Color='Black') OR VALUE NOT IN (1,2,3))
```

Or you could write a dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @Statement NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @Statement = 'Select Sum(Cost) as Cost, Car, Make INTO #TempTable1 WHERE   Date > ''04/21/2020'''
IF(@value in (1,2,3))
  BEGIN
    SET @Statement=@Statement+' and Color=''Black'''
  END
SET @Statement=@Statement+ ' GROUP BY Car,Make ' 
EXEC sp_executesql   @Statement
```

Alternative:

```
Select Sum(Cost) as Cost, Car, Make
INTO #TempTable1
WHERE 
  1=1 and Date > '04/21/2020'
AND  
    CASE WHEN @flag N (1,2,3) 
    THEN color
    ELSE 'Black'
    END = 'Black'
GROUP BY
  Car, Make
```

Last alternative:

```
IF @value in (1,2,3) 
BEGIN
    Select Sum(Cost) as Cost, Car, Make
    INTO #TempTable1
    WHERE 1=1 and Date > '04/21/2020'
    AND color='Black'
    GROUP BY Car, Make
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    Select Sum(Cost) as Cost, Car, Make
    INTO #TempTable1
    WHERE 1=1 and Date > '04/21/2020'
    GROUP BY Car, Make
END
```

Comment: Is there a way I can create a variable and set it to color=black if @Value = 1,2,3 and then use that variable in my clause without it being dynamic SQL. Only add the additional where clause as DYNAMIC something like in EDIT in my question

Comment: if you want to go that route you need to use dynamic SQL. I will update my answer with a couple more alternatives

Comment: basically the SELECT statement is very big and I'd like to stay away from making it dynamic SQL. I'd only like to do that to the where clause. Thank you

Comment: @Koosh Creating a variable and using it in your clause as you describe **IS** dynamic SQL.